# Using await with replaceAll's callback function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying out a Chrome extension.

How do I get a `replaceAll`'s callback function to use `await` ?

```
window.onload = async () =>
{
    const elem = document.getElementById('#myID');
    const elem_modified = elem.replaceAll(regex, await myFunction);
    document.getElementById('#myID').innerHTML = elem_modified;
}
```

myFunction :

```
const myFunction = async (str) =>
{
    const items = [...str.matchAll(regex)][0];

    // Do some manipulation

    let amount = number * value;

    const amount_modified = await calculate(amount);

    console.log("amount_modified = " + amount_modified); // This shows correctly

    return items[0] + ' (' + amount_modified + ')';
}
```

The result is like

> over [object Promise] to many people

Comment: 'const elem_modified = await elem.replaceAll(regex, await myFunction); 'does not do the trick?

Comment: @Edoldin - No, it wouldn't.

Comment: Why does it need to be async at all? What is `calculate` doing that requires you to await it?

Comment: You can't do this with `replaceAll`. You have to find all occurrences, call `myFunction` for each occurrence, await them and then replace them. `replaceAll` doesn't know how to handle a promise.

Comment: "What is calculate doing that requires you to await it?" - I am using `fetch`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't, `replaceAll` — like lots of functions that support callbacks — doesn't expect a promise as a return value from the callback. In the vast majority of cases, you can't usefully pass a promise to code that doesn't expect one. (`map` is one exception to that rule.)

You haven't provided a runnable example or an example of your regular expression, but the general shape of the solution here will be:

1. Split the string into parts (the segments you want to pass through your `async` function and the segments between them).
2. Start the calculation for each of the segments you want to process and get a promise (from your `async` function) of the result; for the segments in-between, just create a promise fulfilled to the original segment value.
3. Wait for all of those to complete by using `Promise.all`, `await`ing the promise it provides. (That's assuming it's okay to start processing all the segments at once, rather than waiting for the processing of one to end before starting processing the next.)
4. Assemble a new string from the updated segments and the segments that used to be between them.

Here's a rough sketch that isolates the numbers in a string and builds a new string with the numbers doubled. This version doesn't, of course, need to be `async` at all, but you can substitute a truly async operation for `calculate`:

```js
async function calculate(str) {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10)); // Just so we do actually do something async
    return str ? String(Number(str) * 2) : str;
}
async function example(str) {
    const rex1 = /(\d+)/; // Note the capture group, so `split` retains the delimiter between matches
    const rex2 = /^\d+$/; // Same as above, but full string match and no capture group
    // #1
    const parts = str.split(rex1);
    // #2 and #3 (the `await`)
    const updated = await Promise.all(parts.map(async (part) => {
        if (rex2.test(part)) {
            return await calculate(part);
        }
        return part;
    }));
    // #4
    return updated.join("");
}

example("Testing 1 2 3 testing")
.then((result) => console.log(result))
.catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

---

Side note: The DOM event system won't pay any attention to the promise the `async` function you're using as an event handler returns, so it's important not to allow any errors (promise rejections) to terminate that handler, since those rejections will be unhandled.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution Crowder. I got my extension working. The RegEx was `/(\$[\d,*?\.*?]+\s*[m|b]illion)/i` - So `map` is the only one that 'understands' async / await ! Amazing.

Comment: @anjanesh - Glad to help! It's not that `map` understands promises -- it doesn't -- it's just that `map` returns the promises the `async` callback function returns in the array it returns. (Similarly, you can chain promises together in series with `reduce`, but don't -- there are better ways [unless you're doing functional programming with predefined reducer functions].) The *reason* `forEach` and `replaceAll` and such can't handle the callback returning a promise is that those methods are *synchronous*, and promise fulfillment values are never available synchronously. :-) Happy coding!